# Why does "format.json { render :show }" not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I've been following along with the book Agile Web Development with Rails 4. The following code is a little confusing:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
  ...
```

I am not sure whether this line

```
format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
```

really works, because I cannot find any JSON content through the inspect tool in the Chrome.

Also, the "render :show" seems to reference to the jbuilder:

```
views/line_items/show.json.jbuilder
```

I tried to add some "p ..." in the `show.json.jbuilder`, but I failed to see any output in the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `respond_to` block, only one of those `format...` lines will run and it depends on the type of request. The `format.json` line will only run if the initial request was an ajax request. If the request was a normal form submission, then only the `format.html` line is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether some syntax is legal, you can always just ask Ruby herself:

```sh
ruby -c -e 'format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }'
# Syntax OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very legal.

In Ruby there are multiple ways to pass a block (an anonymous function) to a method. For this example lets use [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

We can use `do...end`:

```
['oof', 'rab'].map do |s| 
  s.reverse 
end
# => ["foo", "bar"]
```

Or we can use an inline block:

```
['oof', 'rab'].map { |s| s.reverse }
# => ["foo", "bar"]
```

We can also use [procs and lambdas](http://awaxman11.github.io/blog/2013/08/05/what-is-the-difference-between-a-block/) but lets not get sidetracked here. The Ruby parser does not care which of the above you use - however there are some pretty strong community conventions:

> Prefer {...} over do...end for single-line blocks. Avoid using {...}
>   for multi-line blocks (multi-line chaining is always ugly). Always use
>   do...end for "control flow" and "method definitions" (e.g. in
>   Rakefiles and certain DSLs). Avoid do...end when chaining.
>   https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

So lets see if we can make that example a bit less cryptic:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html do 
      redirect_to(@line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.')
    end
    format.json do
      render(:show, status: :created, location: @line_item)
      # or a more idiomatically correct API response
      # head( :created, location:  @line_item )
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! But it is not what I want... The previous title of my question is misleading. I have fixed it.